# Why does the overidden run method in java.lang.Thread produce a bizarre output?

Tags: multithreading

I ran the following code.

```
public class ThreadDemo extends Thread{
      public void run(){ 
            System.out.println("running thread name 
                    is:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());

             System.out.println("Current Thread Priority 
                    is"+Thread.currentThread().getPriority());
    }

     public static void main(String args[]){
         ThreadDemo t1=new ThreadDemo();
         ThreadDemo t2=new ThreadDemo();

         t1.start();
         t2.start();

 }
}
```

**I expected to get the following output:**

```
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread priority is:5
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:5
```

But I got the same output given below everytime I run the code.

```
running thread name is:Thread-0
running thread name is:Thread-1
running thread priority is:5
running thread priority is:5
```

Why the first System.out.println is printed twice and then second System.out.printlln printed twice?
Why this bizarre behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a 100m race. The judge fires a gun, and the runners start running. What you expect is that runner #1 starts, passes 50m, and 100m mark, then runner #2 starts, passes 50m, and 100m mark.

That's not how races work, though. What *actually happens* is they run kind of in parallel; both of them start (one can be a bit faster than the other), both pass the halfway (on one order or another), both finish (maybe in the same order, maybe one got a spurt of speed). It could happen that one of them stumbles, and doesn't even reach the halfway point before the other runs past the finish line; but that is a rare occasion, hardly to be expected. One should expect runners of similar skill in a race to run more-or-less in parallel.

That is what "in parallel" means, and is why multithreading exists in the first place. Each thread is a runner, that starts when you tell it to, and runs in parallel with any other existing threads. If you want to execute your code sequentially — as a relay, not a race (i.e. "non-bizarre" in your words) — you probably shouldn't use multithreading :)